# Write_Prometheus plugin with basic auth

Tags: cassandra, prometheus, collectd

I am testing the below Write_Prometheus plugin to send the cassandra metrics to prometheus server which is external machine but i see that all metrics are sending without any basic auth happening.
so i need help here that how i can send my metrics using basic auth to prometheus server .
https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Write_Prometheus

I try to add auth file under the Write_Prometheus plugin and restarted the plugin but it didn't help so looking some idea that how i can enforce basic auth while sending the metrics to propemetus server.

Comment: This question reads to me, like it's about configuration of mentioned plugin. If that's the case - Stack Overflow is a wrong venue for this question. Consider asking at one of the: [devops.se], [su], [sf] (consult their respective help pages to identify most appropriate for your situation). Also, I recommend you to clarify what exactly is happening in your situation before asking there: link to plugin says it's exposes metrics for standard scraping, but you asking about sending metrics (does that imply use of remote_write?)

Comment: Thanks !Let me explain it , I have Cassandra cluster running where i am capturing the metrics on node and sending those metrics to prometeus server using the write_prometeus plugin whereas i noticed that metrics are pulling fine by Prometeus but it is without any auth.  like curl http://<nodeip>:portno but this is happening without any auth so want to see option that how to enable the basic auth so prometeus should pull metrics using some auth method instead of direct fetching,